# pass color arguments to pic command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to pass colors as argument to the pic command `\pic at (-4,0) {bubblelab={label=A,color=orange, fill=orange length=0.8, scale=0.8}};`but i've got undefined color error. Do you have any idea how to do so?

[image]

**main.tex**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre

%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{gris}{RGB}{158,158,158}
\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,178,0}
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{RGB}{190,0,120}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{types/f2d_label}

\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={15cm},totalheight={15cm},keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pictparam, scale=0.1]
    %\pic {droitegrad={min=-20, max=80, secondsgrad=-18, secondbgrad=-10, firstlab=-10, secondlab=0, lastlab=20, dscale=20}};
    %\pic {bubblelab={label=A, point=-4, scale=0.8}};
    \draw[->] (-20,0) -- (5+80,0);
    \foreach \x in {-20,-18,...,80}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,20pt) -- (0pt,-20pt);
    }
    \foreach \x in {-20,-10,...,80}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,45pt) -- (0pt,-45pt);
    }
    \foreach \x in {-10,0,...,20}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[inner sep=10pt, below, scale=0.9] {\x};
    }
    %\draw[color=orange, ->] (-4,2) -- ++(0,8) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {A};
    \pic at (-4,0) {bubblelab={label=A,color=orange, fill=orange length=0.8, scale=0.8}};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (4,2) -- (4,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {B};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (14,2) -- (14,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {C};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (28,2) -- (28,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {D};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (52,2) -- (52,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {E};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (72,2) -- (72,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

**f2d_label.tex**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bblarrow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example:
% \pic[fill=green, text=green, draw=black, opacity=.7] at (5,0) {bubblelab={label=3, color=3, length=2, scale=1}};
%
%%  Labelle à bulle
\tikzset{
    pics/bubblelab/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{bubblelab/.cd,#1}
            \def\pv##1{
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bubblelab/##1}
            }
        \draw[color=\pv{color}, ->] (0,0.2) -- ++(0,\pv{length}) 
        node[color=\pv{color},fill=\pv{fill}!20, anchor=south, scale=\pv{scale}, circle] {\pv{label}};;
    }
    },
    bubblelab/.cd,
    label/.initial=A,
    color/.initial=black,
    fill/.initial=black,
    length/.initial=0.8,
    scale/.initial=0.8,
}
```

I looked on internet and stackexchange, but didn't find anything to help :/

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be a bit more careful with spaces. Change your file `f2d_label.tex` to become

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% bblarrow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example:
% \pic[fill=green, text=green, draw=black, opacity=.7] at (5,0) {bubblelab={label=3, color=3, length=2, scale=1}};
%
%%  Labelle à bulle
\tikzset{
    pics/bubblelab/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{bubblelab/.cd,#1}
            \def\pv##1{% <- added
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bubblelab/##1}% <- added
            }
        \draw[color=\pv{color}, ->] (0,0.2) -- ++(0,\pv{length}) 
        node[color=\pv{color},fill=\pv{fill}!20, anchor=south, scale=\pv{scale}, circle] {\pv{label}};;
    }
    },
    bubblelab/.cd,
    label/.initial=A,
    color/.initial=black,
    fill/.initial=black,
    length/.initial=0.8,
    scale/.initial=0.8,
}
```

where the changes are marked by `<- added`. (If you were to use the `/.expanded` key as in `\draw[color/.expanded=\pv{color},...`, some of the spaces would get removed automatically.)

Also, in your main file, a comma is missing in

```
\pic at (-4,0) {bubblelab={label=A,color=orange, fill=orange length=0.8, scale=0.8}};
```

which needs to become

```
 \pic at (-4,0) {bubblelab={label=A,color=orange, fill=orange,length=0.8, scale=0.8}};
```

with a comma after `orange`. (Note that I removed `types/` in `\input{types/f2d_label}` because I did not want to create a subfolder in the folder I am working.)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}%  permet de dessiner des figures, des graphiques
\usepackage{adjustbox}% permet de déterminer une taille de fenêtre

%%  FONT
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tgadventor}% paquet de police de caractère TGadventor
\usepackage{sansmath}%  Copie-colle la police active dans \sfdefault (/!\ N'EST PAS UNE POLICE DE CARACTÈRES)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{245,128,37}
\definecolor{bleu}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{gris}{RGB}{158,158,158}
\definecolor{vert}{RGB}{0,178,0}
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{violet}{RGB}{190,0,120}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{f2d_label} % \input{types/f2d_label}

\tikzset{pictparam/.style={font={\sansmath\sffamily}, thick, line cap=round, line join=round, >=latex, x=1.0cm, y=1.0cm, scale=1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{width={15cm},totalheight={15cm},keepaspectratio}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pictparam, scale=0.1]
    %\pic {droitegrad={min=-20, max=80, secondsgrad=-18, secondbgrad=-10, firstlab=-10, secondlab=0, lastlab=20, dscale=20}};
    %\pic {bubblelab={label=A, point=-4, scale=0.8}};
    \draw[->] (-20,0) -- (5+80,0);
    \foreach \x in {-20,-18,...,80}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,20pt) -- (0pt,-20pt);
    }
    \foreach \x in {-20,-10,...,80}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,45pt) -- (0pt,-45pt);
    }
    \foreach \x in {-10,0,...,20}
    {   \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0,0) node[inner sep=10pt, below, scale=0.9] {\x};
    }
    %\draw[color=orange, ->] (-4,2) -- ++(0,8) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {A};
    \pic at (-4,0) {bubblelab={label=A,color=orange,fill=orange,length=0.8, scale=0.8}};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (4,2) -- (4,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {B};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (14,2) -- (14,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {C};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (28,2) -- (28,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {D};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (52,2) -- (52,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {E};
    \draw[color=orange, ->] (72,2) -- (72,10) node[fill=orange!20, anchor=south, scale=0.8, circle] {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to use a text comparator to see the difference between the two code... I wouldn't have found the problem, searching too far while it was just a problem of space :/ ... thx